# C++でthisを使って同じクラス内のメンバにアクセスしても問題ない？

Tags: c++

現在C++でDxLibを使って簡単なゲームを作成しています。
クラスのメンバ関数から同一クラス内の他のメンバ関数やメンバ変数にアクセスするとき`this->m_X`というようにしているのですが、オープンソースをみているとthisを使ったコードは少ないように思えます。
これによって処理速度や生産性が落ちたりするのでしょうか？どうかご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

実行処理速度は全く変わりません。コンパイル処理速度は多少変わるかもしれません。生産性はエディタ次第ですが、タイプ数が６文字増えることになるでしょうか。

- [C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)
- [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)

どちらも言及すらされていないほどどちらでも構わない内容のようです。